# Sound does not play when locking WinXP

Tags: windows-xp, audio, logoff

If I press the Windows-L combination to lock my PC the "Windows Logoff" sound does not play.  It used to but at some point it stopped.  I installed only trustworthy apps on my system and it is pretty clean so I don't think it is a virus.

I checked the sounds in the control panel and "Windows Logoff" is set.  Is there a sound associated with the key combination?  Perhaps something in the registry?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The last thing I installed that I think may have caused this (and I also notice my screen saver never kicks in) is iTunes.  It runs about 4-5 separate processes.  I will see about starting up without them to see if it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Win + L does not log you off, it just locks the desktop. This allows programs to continue to run.

Answer (score 0):

Win + L used to make a sound (the same sound assigned to logoff).
After entering my password it would make a sound (the same sound assigned to login).

I don't know how to get this working again.  It's not a big deal really but if something is not working on my PC as it used to I get worried.

I think the screen saver not activating is related to my wireless keyboard.  I use a direct-connect USB mouse.

UPDATE: Screen saver just kicked in.  I think it is the wireless keyboard which may be interfering.

SOLUTION: I discovered today that my front speakers were plugged into the wrong audio inlet and so I was not getting front speaker sound.  I have a 6 speaker system and so I didn't notice when other sounds played.  Now sounds are playing fine.